# method declared outside of class deceleration could not be inherited by child class in javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, prototype

```
// declared class vehicle
function Vehicle(make,model,year){
  this.make=make
  this.model=model
  this.year=year

}
// 2 - Add a function to the Vehicle prototype called start which returns the string //"VROOM!"
 Vehicle.prototype.start=function(){
  return "VROOM!"
}

// declared child class car
function Car(make,model,year){
  Vehicle.apply(this,arguments)
  this.numWheels=4

}
// assigning the constructor
Car.prototype.constructor=Object.create(Vehicle.constructor)
// changing the pointing of constructor back to car
Car.prototype.constructor=Car;
var sedan=new Car("Tractor", "John Deere", 1999)
console.log(sedan.start()) 
//sedan.start() gives error but if i declare it inside vehicle class does not
```

Comment: You've not set the prototype of `Car` to be `Vehicle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `Car()` to inherit the methods defined on `Vehicle()`'s prototype, you can simply use:

```
Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype);
```

Here [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) method is used to create a new object and make it the value of `Car.prototype`. The new object has `Vehicle.prototype` as its prototype and will therefore inherit all the methods available on `Vehicle.prototype`. So, there is no need to use the below logic:

```
// assigning the constructor
Car.prototype.constructor=Object.create(Vehicle.constructor)
```

DEMO:

```js
// declared class vehicle
function Vehicle(make, model, year) {
  this.make = make
  this.model = model
  this.year = year
}

// 2 - Add a function to the Vehicle prototype called start which returns the string //"VROOM!"
Vehicle.prototype.start = function() {
  return "VROOM!"
}

// declared child class car
function Car(make, model, year) {
  Vehicle.apply(this, arguments)
  this.numWheels = 4
}
Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype);
Car.prototype.constructor = Car;
var sedan = new Car("Tractor", "John Deere", 1999)
console.log(sedan.start())
```

**A better approach using [`Classes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):**

ECMAScript 2015 introduces class syntax to JavaScript as a way to write reusable classes using easier, cleaner syntax, which is more similar to classes in C++ or Java. Here we'll convert the Vehicle and Car example from prototypal inheritance to classes, to show you how it's done.

DEMO:

```js
class Vehicle {
  constructor(make, model, year) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
  }
  start() {
    return "VROOM!"
  };
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
  constructor(make, model, year) {
    super(); // Now 'this' is initialized by calling the parent constructor.
  }
  bonet() {
    return "VROOM2!"
  };
}

var sedan = new Car("Tractor", "John Deere", 1999)
console.log(sedan.start())
console.log(sedan.bonet())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Shouldn't i have to change constructor of Car.prototype to Car again. From what i know if i didn't change it will point to vehicles constructor

Comment: Ok, but I am not able to get why do you need that for. Could you share a test case scenario where you are having an issue if you don't change the constructor of `Car.prototype` to `Car` again.

Comment: testcase--> because suppose if i add a method like car.bonet() it would also be adding itself to vechicle's constructor if i didn't change it explicitly to vechicle constructor at least this is what i think

Comment: Ok, then we will also need to have to change the constructor of Car.prototype to Car again.

Comment: thnks again for your response

Comment: My pleasure. I have also added a ES6 classes demo, where we don't need to anything like that. Its so simple with classes.

Answer (score 1):

These lines of code don't make sense:

```
// assigning the constructor
Car.prototype.constructor=Object.create(Vehicle.constructor)
// changing the pointing of constructor back to car
Car.prototype.constructor=Car;
```

They don't make sense because making an assignment to that constructor and then immediately making *another* assignment means that the first assignment will have absolutely no effect on anything.

I *think* what you need instead is:

```
// assigning the constructor
Car.prototype=Object.create(Vehicle.prototype)
// changing the pointing of constructor back to car
Car.prototype.constructor=Car;
```

Now you'll have the `Car` prototype refer to the `Vehicle` prototype, so that `Car` instances will have both in their prototype chains.

In this modern world of 2020, you can do all that with [class declarations.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: thanks a lot !! in my course i didn't started with class till now